# TinyMCE - Allow text as direct child of <table> and/or <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have been struggling for about 3 hours, both testing solutions and googled as a maniac.
I haven't found any solution to this specific problem.

**Problem:**
TinyMCE wont allow me to insert text as a direct "child" in:

```
<table>
<tr>
<tbody>
```

**Example:** I use TinyMCE Option > Source Code.
Input:

```
<table>
<tr></tr>
 *[generated]*
</table>
```

**When** I then press "OK" on the Source Code window the output is the following:

```
*[generated]*
<table>
<tbody>
<tr></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**What happens** is that TinyMCE validates the markup as invalid and adds my "text" ([generated]) outside the table.
**WHY:** I want this solution because a cms engine takes the static HTML and find special elements to insert data dynamic data. The data will contain valid HTML and my [generated] tag will not exist in the generated page afterwards.

**What I have done?** I have been trying:

```
extend_valid_elements: "table[#text], table[text], tr[#text],tr[text]",
valid_elements:        "table[theader|tbody|#text|]",
valid_children:        "table[theader|tbody|#text]"
```

I cant possibly paste all different elements I have been trying to allow with. But now I am out of ideas. And I dont want to cook a dirty hack for this.

Is there anyone out there who can help me?
My settings is all standard, I have just added som plugins.

> verify_html: false,
>   cleanup: false,

But whatever plugin/setting that makes this, I will remove.

English is not my mother tounge, but I'll hope I made myself clear.

Comment: i have no solution for this, but it might help to writa into the official tinymce forum. Maybe an admin or developer will repond directly to you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm dealing with the same problem, and can't find anything on the tinyMCE forum.

Comment: Try extending `tbody` with `valid_elements:        "table[theader|tbody|#text|],tbody[tr|#text]",
valid_children:        "table[theader|tbody|#text],tbody[tr|#text]"`

Answer (score 0):

I have a small amount of good news for you. TinyMCE docs suggest that valid_elements and valid_children allow some special control characters. One of those characters is an allow all option.

However, it still needs to be an element which begins and ends with < > rather than #. Even better might be a comment, so

That is to say you could set `valid_children` to '*' or '#*#'. Not sure how it will cope with the replacement.

I would also take a look at your cms docs. If it's clever enough to deal with html attributes you could go that route, or us html comments as mentioned above.

Finally you could use a beforeload and beforesave style function as part of MCE or in your own code to convert any #something# to  and then back from.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_children